# Is there a way to integrate with Google apps to read/write the text in the open document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

We want to have a web app that communicates with Google docs and when the user clicks a button in our web app, it can query Google docs to find what is presently selected in the editor and replace that text.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there is! At Google I/O last week they launched Google Scripts for Docs

So head back to 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/
In order to see the documentation

Also here is the video from the I/O event:
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/327928222

Enjoy!

Comment: OK. The API does not do what David wanted to originally, be able to detect the selected text.  But I still figured I should update the answer in case people come in here from a Google search.